# Can it be represented by convolution and multiplication

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convolution

I have functions $A, B, F, S$ that are zero on $(-\infty, 0)$.
And I have successfully represented the below equation as convolution and multiplication:

$\int_0^t {dt_1} \int_0^t {dt_2} B(t - t_2)F(t_2 - t_1)S(t - t_1)F(t_1)$

$=\int_0^t {dt_1}F(t_1) S(t - t_1)\int_{t_1}^t {dt_2} B(t - t_2)F(t_2 - t_1)$

$=\int_0^t {dt_1}F(t_1) S(t - t_1)\int_0^{t-t_1} {dt'_2} B(t - t_1 - t'_2)F(t'_2)$

$=\int_0^t {dt'_1}F(t - t'_1) S(t'_1)\int_0^{t'_1} {dt'_2} B(t'_1 - t'_2)F(t'_2)$

$=\int_0^t {dt'_1}F(t - t'_1) S(t'_1)(B*F)(t'_1)$

$=(F * (S(B*F)))(t)$

where $(F*G)(t)=\int_0^tF(t-t')G(t')dt'$. The first equality holds because $F(t_2-t_1)=0$ for $t_2<t_1$. The second equality results by substitution $t'_2=t_2-t_1$. The third equality results by substitution $t'_1=t-t_1$.

It doesn't look like it can be represented as a convolution at first, but actually it turns out that it is represented by a combination of convolution and multiplication of functions.

But I failed to represent the below equation as a combination of convolution and multiplication. Is it possible, or not? If it is not possible, how can one prove that it is not possible?

$\int_0^t {dt_1} \int_0^t {dt_2} \int_0^t {dt_3} B(t - t_3)F(t_3 - t_2)S(t - t_2)F(t_2 - t_1)F(t_1)$

For me, it doesn't look like it is possible. But like the equation in the first line which doesn't seem to be represented as convolution at first glance, it may be possible. If anyone succeeds, please let me know. Thank you.

---

Is it possible to represent the following function as a convolution?

$$  \int_0^tdt_1 \int_0^tdt_2 \int_0^tdt_3 A(t-t_3)F(t_3-t_2)S(t-t_2)F(t_2-t_1)S(t_3-t_1)F(t_1) $$

Comment: Do not write  "functions $B(x), F(x), S(x)$ that are zero for $x<0$" -- write "functions $B,F,S$ that are zero on $(-\infty,0)$" instead.
Do not write $B(t)*F(t)$ --write $(B*F)(t)$ instead.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, while I certainly agree with [you](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386026/can-it-be-represented-by-convolution-and-multiplication#comment984159_386026) about what usage is proper, I think that the usage in the parent post is so familiar that, while technically improper, it is not really any more objectionable than writing $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x^2)$ instead of something like the more technically correct but horrible $\bigl(D(x \mapsto x^2)\bigr)(x)$.  Certainly I have seen the notation in the post used by mathematicians wiser and abler than I.

Comment: @LSpice : (i) I have certainly seen expressions such as "function $f(x)$", especially in older papers. (ii) In your example, the "correct" expression is indeed horrible, whereas the expression $\frac d{dx}(x^2)$ is not really objectionable at all, since it is easy and natural to attach a meaning to the derivative of an expression (rather than of a function). (iii) In my suggestions, in contrast with that example, the correct versions are, not only not horrible, but they are also neater, more compact, and easier to understand than the incorrect ones, especially $B(t)*F(t)$ vs. $(B*F)(t)$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I have changed the notation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$
Most likely, the integral
$$I:=\int_0^t dt_1 \int_0^t dt_2 \int_0^t dt_3\, B(t-t_3)F(t_3-t_2)
S(t-t_2)F(t_2-t_1)F(t_1)$$
cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions -- because the finite interval $[0,t]$ is not a group (or even a semigroup), and the restrictions $t_2\in[0,t]$ and $t_3\in[0,t]$ are unjustified, since the integrand contains no factors depending only on $t_2$ or only on $t_3$. Since the functions $B,F,S$ are zero on $(-\infty,0)$, the correct(ed) form of the integral $I$ seems to be
\begin{align*}
    \tilde I&:=\int_\R dt_1 \int_\R dt_2 \int_\R dt_3\, B(t-t_3)F(t_3-t_2)
S(t-t_2)F(t_2-t_1)F(t_1) \\
&=\int_\R {dt_2}\, (B*F)(t-t_2)S(t-t_2)(F*F)(t_2) \\ 
&=\Big(\big((B*F)S\big)*(F*F)\Big)(t),
\end{align*}
so that $\tilde I$ is expressed in terms of products and convolutions.

---

The similarly corrected integral added later to the OP,
\begin{align*}
    J&:=\int_\R dt_1 \int_\R dt_2 \int_\R dt_3\,  A(t-t_3)F(t_3-t_2)S(t-t_2)F(t_2-t_1)S(t_3-t_1)F(t_1),
\end{align*}
probably cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions.

A way to check it may be by the following *shift* observation, **which addresses a comment by LSpice**:

> Suppose we want to show that a function $f$ cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions of functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$. To do this, we build all possible binary trees as follows. The nodes of such a tree are nonempty subsets of the set $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. To each node $J$ there corresponds an expression in terms of products and/or convolutions of the functions $(f_j\colon j\in J)$.
> The root of the tree is the set $[n]$. Each node is split into two branches, whose roots are nonempty subsets, which become the nodes next up the tree. Each node is marked either by $p$ (for "product") or $c$ (for "convolution"), depending on whether the daughter expressions of the node get multiplied or convolved.

> Then the functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$ get shifted horizontally, starting with the leaves of the tree. If two adjacent leaves are the branches of a $p$-node, their corresponding functions get shifted by the same real number, say $u$. After that, the two leaves get deleted and their parent node is marked by the same shift $u$. If two adjacent leaves are the branches of a $c$-node, their corresponding functions get shifted by two arbitrary real numbers, say $u_1$ and $u_2$. After that, the two leaves get deleted and their parent node is marked by shift $u_1+u_2$. This process then continues down to the root. For every $p$-node encountered during this process, the shifts assigned to the daughter branches get equalized, say by imposing the corresponding equality constraint. Finally, at the root of the tree, we check if the function $f$ has the resulting shift property.

As a comparatively simple case, suppose that a function $f$ can be expressed in terms of products and convolutions of functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
    f=\Big(\prod_{j\in J_1}f_j\Big)*\cdots*\Big(\prod_{j\in J_m}f_j\Big), \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\{J_1,\dots,J_m\}$ is a partition of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Suppose next that, for each $k=1,\dots,m$ and each $j\in J_k$, the function $f_j$ is shifted horizontally by a real number $u_k$. Then $f$ gets shifted by $u_1+\dots+u_m$.

For any given functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$, there may be only finitely many representations of $f$ in the form (1); so, we can try and exhaust all of them.

---

By considering all the distinguishable trees, it is not hard to see that the integral $J$ cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions. This can be done even with zero shifts, and even with the additional assumption that $A=S=F$, as shown in this [Mathematica notebook](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ7V5BXZU62NRsnkzXX85yXVcMQLRuE8arBy); you can also see the [notebook's pdf image](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZwJ5BXZQ7xxQazlgjjkAfhWJP3gF5THeSHV).

A few comments on that notebook:

1. E.g., the possible representation $c(F,p(c(F,F),c(F,p(F,F))))$ of the integral $J$ (with $A=S=F$) is the result of the application of the sequence $(c, p, c, c, p)$ of operations $c$[=convolution] or $p$[=product] to the (unlabeled) tree $(x, ((x, x), (x, (x, x))))$, where $x$ represents any leaf. In our case (concerning the integral $J$), there are $6$ trees (each with $6$ leaves) and $2^5$ sequences of operations $c$ or $p$. So, there are $6\times2^5=192$ possible representations of the integral $J$ in terms of products and convolutions.
2. For positive real $K$ and $s$, let $f_{K,s}:=Kf_s$, where $f_s$ is the density function of the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $s^2$. Then for any positive real $K_1,K_2,s_1,s_2$ we have
   $$f_{K_1,s_1}*f_{K_2,s_2}=f_{K,s}\quad\text{for}\quad K=K_1K_2,\ s=\sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2},$$
   $$f_{K_1,s_1}f_{K_2,s_2}=f_{K,s}\quad\text{for}\quad K=\frac{K_1K_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2}},\ s=\frac{s_1s_2}{\sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2}}.$$
   So, the family $(f_{K,s})$ is closed with respect to operations $c$ and $p$.
3. So, taking e.g. $F=f_{1,1}$, we see that each possible representation of the integral $J$ in terms of products and convolutions (such as e.g. $c(F,p(c(F,F),c(F,p(F,F))))$) is of the form $f_{K,s}$ and thus is determined by the corresponding pair $(K,s)$ of positive real numbers. The integral $J$ for $F=f_{1,1}$ is also of the form $f_{K,s}$, actually with $(K,s)=(\frac{1}{8 \pi ^{3/2}},\sqrt{2})$.
4. The direct calculation done in the mentioned Mathematica notebook shows that none of the $192$ pairs $(K,s)$ corresponding to the $192$ possible representations of the integral $J$ in terms of products and convolutions equals $(\frac{1}{8 \pi ^{3/2}},\sqrt{2})$. So, the integral $J$ cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions.

Comment: It seems like there must be some sort of mechanical procedure for formally converting expressions of the form in the original post to expressions involving only convolution and multiplication, when this is possible.  Do you know any easy criterion that identifies when it is *not* possible?

Comment: @LSpice : I think this is a good comment, but I don't know of such an algorithm or a criterion of whether it would succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Also, I came up with another integral representation which I added in parent post. It doesn't seem possible. Like @LSpice mentioned, I'd love to have criteria or something that one can tell it is possible to represent as convolution or not

Comment: @LSpice : Now your comment has been addressed: There is a way to identify at least some (maybe all) situations when such integrals cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions.

Comment: I'm not sure your shift observation quite works for this problem.  For instance with the form $S(F*G)$ one needs to translate $F,G$ by $u$ and $S$ by $2u$ in order to translate the entire form by $2u$.  The problem seems to be more subtle than this - it should not be possible to express this form via convolution, but this is because a certain graph underlying the form is "crossing" rather than "non-crossing" in nature which is preventing it from splitting into lower multilinearity forms.  Unfortunately have to run, may explain later.

Comment: @TerryTao : Thank you for your comment. I also noticed the mistake. I think the idea should work, though. Working on a correction.

Comment: I think the criterion should now be correct. However, there are apparently too many trees to consider.

Comment: It is now shown that your second integral cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions.

Comment: The way of thinking of these expressions is to represent them as a graph where each integration variable represents a vertex (plus two distinguished vertices representing $0$ and $t$) and each factor represents a line. So $F(t_3-t_2)$ is a line labelled $F$ joining $t_2$ to $t_3$ and $G(t_1)$ is a line labelled $G$ joining $0$ to $t_1$...

Comment: ... With this notation, multiplying two expressions of the type you're considering corresponds to just joining the two graphs at $0$ and $t$, while convolving them corresponds to joining the $t$ of one graph with the $0$ of the other. It is then easy to see when a graph can be obtained from elementary ones using only these operations.

Comment: This graphical notation is due to Feynman by the way: these are Feynman diagrams with two legs.

Comment: @MartinHairer : Thank you for your comments. This seems to be a nice graphical way to represent such integrals, which may help to express the integral in terms of products and convolutions when such an expression exists. However, I have not had any experience with graphs and don't see an easy algorithm using such graphs to prove that such an expression does not exist when that is the case. Is such an algorithm described somewhere? Or maybe just some properties of the graph implying the nonexistence? Terry Tao mentioned a crossing property which apparently implies the nonexistence ...

Comment: @IosifPinelis For that all you'd need to show is that for any two distinct labelled graphs you can find a choice of functions (one per label) so that the two functions represented by the two graphs are distinct. I haven't really thought about that, but it doesn't sound like it should be too hard...

Comment: @MartinHairer : Thank you for your response. However, I am not sure how to use this. These graphs seem to be just another way to write the corresponding integrals. It appears to me that you are suggesting to compare the integral in question with all the integrals expressed in terms of products and convolutions, probing various choices of the "atomic" functions ($A,S,F$ in the OP) . Is that so? And if so, would such a comparison substantially differ from what is described in the last part of my answer?

Comment: @MartinHairer : It would be of interest, I think, if there is a (topological?) invariant of such graphs with respect to products and convolutions.

Comment: The characterisation of these graphs is that their edges can be (uniquely) directed in such a way that no simple path joining the distinguished vertex $0$ to the distinguished vertex $t$ ever traverses an edge against its direction.

Comment: @MartinHairer : This is great! Now it is easy to see that the second integral in the OP cannot be expressed in terms of products and convolutions.